# Specify default rendering for placeholder in partial design

Tags: sxa, presentation, placeholders

We have a partial design with an empty placeholder that is being pre-filled with one of its allowed renderings upon page creation. It is not clear where exactly it is being specified for this particular partial design, to automatically add the specific rendering when a content editor creates a new page which uses this partial.

The presentaion details for the page show the item which specifies the placeholder itself, but there is nothing in the details referring to the actual rendering that gets placed within it.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know where this might be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. it's injected via Partial Designs - some partial design has it defined and when layout is composed it is injected to the page. The fact that placeholder matches causes this rendering to pop up inside `ambient-video-placeholder`
2. Ambient Video Container is a "snippet" - there is a change that someone made a clone of regular snippet rendering and presentation is pulled from the Ambient Video Container datasource (see how snippet works [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add,-reuse,-and-edit-a-snippet.html))

You can make a quick test to eliminate **1**

Try to move Ambient Video Container to a different placeholder (i.e from `main` to `footer`, save page and see if Video rendering is still there).
If not, it's probably case **1** if it remains there it's probably **2**.

If **2** is true - open datasource dialog of Ambient Video Container find this datasource item, them verify if Video rendering is present in layout details.
That might be tricky if someone had fantasy and used nested snippets ...

Another way could be finding the rendering by **UID**.

This will work only for **2**, for **1** you will not find rendering representation in the JavaScript.

Open Chrome dev tools and try to find element with this name: `scLayoutDefinition`, it should contain layout definition in JSON.

Try to find your Video rendering and get its **UID**.

Now you can find your rendering in the content using preferred search method (c# code, powershell, SQL), basically your goal is to find and item which contains your UID in one of the fields (I hope you know that presentation is stored in these fields as XML):

- `__Final Renderings`
- `__Renderings`

Comment: Thanks @Alan Płócieniak I found the item in the Branches folder for the specific pages, the rendering was being set at a page level rather than in a partial so your UID trick helped me locate the offending article, cheers.